# unexpected vue warn on a declared prop

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning vuex. I'm facing a strange issue after I've migrated some methods to vuex actions.
I get this error in a component that has worked fine until I've migrated some things to vuex and I've implemented inside the component `...mapGetters` and `...mapActions`

the error is `[Vue warn]: Property or method "isVisible" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`

but in my data I've declared the prop

```js
  data() {
    return {
      id: state.userInfo.id,
      endCursor: state.userInfo.end_cursor,
      nextPageLoaded: false,
      isVisible: false,
      isVideo: null,
      url: null
    }
  }
```

```html
   <div class="modal fade show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" v-if="isVisible">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content h-100 rounded-0">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close mb-3 float-right" @click.prevent="closeZoomModal()">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- display image -->
            <img class="img-fluid w-100 h-100 img-zoom" :src="url" v-if="!isVideo">
            <!-- display video -->
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 h-100" v-else>
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item h-100" :src="url" title=""></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This happen after the user click on the home component to search for ome data and the result component where the error is fires, is loaded.

How I can fix it? can the error be caused from `...mapGetters` or `...mapActions` ?

Comment: Could you share your `..mapGetters` codes portion also?

Comment: @SajibKhan I've debugged the code and I've discovered that the problem isn't with `...mapGetters` the problem is with the `data()` where I need to use the mapped getters. Any help about this?

Comment: `...mapGetters` should be used inside `computed`, not inside `data`!

Comment: The reason why `isVisible` is not available in template is because the `data` function breaks because `state` is undefined. Therefore none of its contents are available in template and the first unkown prop met in template happens to be `isVisible`.

Answer (score 2):

`state` is not available in `data`. According to docs, you can pass the instance as first param of the data function

```
data: vm => ({
  isVisible: vm.$store.state.isVisible
})
```

... but I personally haven't used this (it doesn't work with Typescript and the component is still in an early lifecycle stage and a lot of things are missing from it). Besides, this is merely an assignment (it only runs once - it's not a getter - so if the state changes after `data` has been set, `data` won't react to it. You'd have to modify the `data` prop itself).

---

So what you need to do is move all store related component properties from `data` into `computed` by using either `...mapState()` (if they're vuex state props), `...mapGetters()` (if they're vuex getters) or use explicit computed syntax:

```
computed: {
  isVisible() {
    return this.$store.state.isVisible; // if store state prop
    // return this.$store.getters['isVisible'] // if store getter
  }
}
```

If you also want to be able to assign to it (as you would to a `data` property), you have to replace the above computed syntax (only getter) with a getter + setter syntax:

```
computed: {
  isVisible: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.state.isVisible;
    },
    set(value) {
      this.$store.dispatch('setVisibility', value);
      // you can also commit mutations `this.$store.commit()` from here
    }
  }
}
```

If you're still having trouble, please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on codesandbox.io and I'll help sort it out.

Comment: @alfaun0 could you follow this answer (@tao explained in detail) ?